# The Google Maps Geolocation API and node-red

Tags: geolocation, node-red, google-geolocation

I have created a simple flow in node-red to get the location. I have  an http request node in which the URL is of google maps API location. The result is produced on the debug node but it is not that accurate. Accuracy is 9379.0. What doesit mean. Is there a better service or way to get the current geo-location.

Comment: You are trying to determine the location of where Node-RED is running?

Comment: it is done. I actually used wifi connections to check the location. Google API was not that much accurate but it is working with Skyhookwireless